# Prevent caching in NSURLSession for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, caching, ios-simulator

I'm trying to find a way to prevent `NSURLSession` from caching responses (in Simulator) by using approach from these questions:

[Prevent NSURLSession from caching responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324394/prevent-nsurlsession-from-caching-responses)

[NSURLCache does not clear stored responses in iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260401/nsurlcache-does-not-clear-stored-responses-in-ios8?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I don't want to use approach from this question:

[Clear NSURLSession Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622967/clear-nsurlsession-cache?rq=1)

which is using `ephemeralSessionConfiguration` call to `NSURLSessionConfiguration` when setting up a new `NSURLSession` instance.

I just want to not cache requests, in worst case clear the cache when application resigns active.
With call `[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses]` in `applicationWillResignActive` execution in app delegate i still get `Cache.db` present and full of cached responses/requests in respective iOS Simulator cache on disk.

Before that, I changed all my `NSURLSessionConfiguration` cache policy to `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`
`NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData`
(tested all three cases, the last one is probably not implemented) instances (and effectively ALL cache policies). Isn't changing cache policy supposed to result in not caching server responses and requests on simulator? Does it depends on storage policy in response headers?

I'm using iOS 9.3 and iOS 10.1 Simulators for iPhone and v. 10 of iOS SDK. Project is in Objective C, maybe full Swift project would behave differently? 
Is this behavior different for simulators and with devices? Why is this happening, is there a solution different from using dependency (can't fall onto one right now for some reason).

Comment: Did you try setting the cachePolicy property on NSMutableURLRequest to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData? Also, set URLCache property on NSURLSessionConfiguration object to nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I was able to fix this by setting the properties- **URLCache** and **requestCachePolicy** on **NSURLSessionConfiguration** to **nil** and **NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData** respectively.

Also, you can try setting the **cachePolicy** property on **NSMutableURLRequest** to **NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData**.

Comment: This was part of my solution. Good that you mentioned `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` - I checked in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequestcachepolicy/nsurlrequestreloadignoringlocalandremotecachedata?language=objc), and behavior for similar value `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData` is not implemented. So beware of this. As an addition - I **manually set cache size to 0** to prevent accidental bugs on this in case something changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

So the rude solution is ... drop the Cache.db file on app resigning. I assume on the simulator you should be able to?!

But, did you try the `ephemeralSessionConfiguration`? Because Apples header doc says:
 * An ephemeral session has no persistent disk storage for cookies,
 * cache or credentials.

Comment: Did you read my question? It explicitly says that I don't want to use `ephemeralSessionConfiguration` (for various reasons).